# Using uncommon Unicode symbols

Tags: fonts, unicode

I'm trying to refer to a function named `Γ⊢ε⦂τ-⇒-Γok` in my paper, but looks like the Unicode characters get stripped off, and I get `--ok` instead.

What I've tried:

- pdflatex with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`,
- xelatex with `\usepackage{fontspec}` (this actually gives some progress, and I can see the uppercase gamma, resulting in `--Γok`!),
- lualatex with either `\usepackage{fontspec}` or `\usepackage{luatextra}` or both — same result.

From what I've understand, the font that's used just doesn't have the corresponding glyphs, but what can I do about that, preferably in an easily reproducible way, as I plan to eventually submit my paper somewhere?

Comment: with xelatex or lualatex just use whatever font you have with those symbols (eg use whatever your browser uses to display the question) note if you submitting your paper as tex source you rely on the institution receiving it to have the same font

Comment: in normal text my firefox on windows uses `Segoe UI Symbol` for that or as you have it in a code block it uses dejavu sans mono.

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly, if I use either `DjeaVu Sans Mono` (which is also used by my browser) or `Fira Code` (that's used in my IDE where I typed this), some symbols still get omitted, like the Unicode analog of $\vdash$ or that funny Unicode colon. That's all probably a sign I better use conventional symbols.

Comment: In what context are you using that combination of symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\pagestyle{empty} % To format the MWE on TeX.SX

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\newfontfamily\symbolfont{STIX Two Math}

\newcommand\functionname[1]{\textnormal{\symbolfont #1}}

\begin{document}
In text mode, \functionname{Γ⊢ε⦂τ-⇒-Γok} is a function.

In math mode, \(\functionname{Γ⊢ε⦂τ-⇒-Γok}\).
\end{document}
```

[image: STIX Two Math sample]

Using a more conventional name is not a bad idea.

Some general tips:

It’s always a good idea to add `\tracinglostchars=2` near the top of your document.  This will at least warn you when a font you use is missing a symbol, instead of logging the error silently.

You need to select a font that contains the symbols you want.  DejaVu Sans, XITS Math, STIX Two Math and Code2000 are especially comprehensive.  FileFormat.info also gives you a list of common fonts that support a given Unicode symbol.